# Destiny 2 How to send friend invites using battletag on PC?

Tags: pc, destiny-2

Whenever searching for fireteam on bungie.net, they provide a battltag they want you to add. I tried searching on google, but there is no such tutorial. How to use it to send friend requests?

Answer (score 3):

The Battletag consists of an Username and an ID. Like this: **Username#2622**

You can only add friends on the Battle.net Client which you have to install first.

**If you already have the Battle.Net Client installed**:
To add a friend you have to go to your Battle.net Client and click on your name on the top right. There should be an Add Friend Button in this Window.

**If you don't have the Battle.net Client installed**:

1. Go to the [Battle.net](https://eu.battle.net) Website.
2. Login to your Battle.Net Account and go to **Account Settings** > **Games & Codes** > **Download Clients**.

[image]

3. Scroll down and you should find **Blizzard Battle.net® app** and download the client.

Comment: When I send a request using Add Friend, do you receive friend request in roster menu? Because whenever I receive requests after sharing my battletag on bungie.net, I receive them directly in-game and not in battle.net app.

Comment: @Aniruddha You should recieve it ingame (if you are playing while the request is comming in) and on the Battle.net Client.